# How to calculate the largest $k$ that satisfies $x\equiv0\quad(mod \ 2^k)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to calculate the largest $k$ that satisfies

$$x\equiv0\quad(mod \ 2^k)$$

---

Let $k_*$ be the largest $k$ that satisfies $x\equiv0\ (mod \ 2^k)$, I'm trying to find the **explicit expression** of $k_*$ with respect to $x$.

- Actually, **if** we enter $x$ in **binary form**, it is obvious that $k_*$ is the number of $0$s to the right of the number. For example, if $x=100101110000$ in binary, then $k_*=4$.
- I already know that *Euclid's algorithm* can find the $k_*$, but what I want to know is, does an explicit expression of $k_*$ exist?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: How is $x$ given if not in binary? In theory you can use [a trig series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2192476/11619) :-)

Comment: Maybe in decimal？Like 2416

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit expression,
but the book
"Hacker's Delight
(2nd edition)"
by Henry Warren
devotes section 5-4
to a number of algorithms
for computing this.

This is called
"the trailing zeros"
problem.

Some of the algorithms
are quite surprising.

The whole book
is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If $\oplus$ represents the binary XOR operation, then $x \oplus (x-1) = 2^{k_* + 1} - 1$, from which $k_*$ can be found with no trouble; we can either be sloppy and say that
$$
    k_* = \lfloor \log_2(x \oplus (x-1))\rfloor
$$
or be more careful and say that
$$
    k_* = \log_2 \frac{(x \oplus (x-1)) + 1}{2}
$$
where in the second expression, we don't have to round down the logarithm.